# Ambient Occlusion map not ideal

Tags: texturing

In UV map editing I tried to bake an ambient occlusion texture, the baking is done but some of the parts of my object are not filled with the white color.[image]

this is the object

In latest update, the top right rectangles in UV map is not filled properly
[image]

The blender file is:
[image]

Comment: Have you checked your normals?

Comment: It looks like there are one or more other objects being incorporated into the the lower part of your spaceships  AO bake.   In the Outliner,  (panel top right)   check that all the hidden objects are also set to be "Disabled in Render" ( little camera icon disabled.)

Comment: thanks @RobinBetts, This solved most of the issue but I still have the following problem the top-left four rectangles not getting filled in the UV map. I already checked the normals the issue was with the "Disable in Render"

Comment: thanks @3fingeredfrog can ya debug how the rectangles problem can be solved?

Comment: Perhaps, but only if you can share your .blend file and add a screenshot showing the problematic area of the UV map.   You can use Blend Exchange https://blend-exchange.com/  to add your .blend file to your original question.

Comment: @3fingeredfrog i've attached the .blend file to the post. thanks for taking the time to debug and help me as I'm new to UV editing and game dev Thank you so much Do you have a YouTube channel or anything? thanks in advance

Comment: @Jassim.. Your question is perfectly good, and well-put, but  after a while,  it and its answer may be closed as a duplicate.. this is an easy slip to make, but it _is_ just a slip, and has cropped up a number of times before on BSE, in various guises. I hope you would understand that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Baking is rendering. Anything set to render will be probed by the 'Ambient Occlusion' preset in the Bake panel.

It's possible for scene elements to be set to render, while not visible in the viewport. That is the case for many building meshes in your scene.. 'Floor and Ceiling' etc.

Switch off the rendering (the little camera icon) for all collections other than 'RocketParts' in your scene, and you will be good.

A way to debug quickly is to check out the scene, *rendered*, using an *Ambient Occlusion* node in your material. That has more options .. ray length, a 'Local Only' setting.. you can even plug that node straight into the *Material Output*, and bake 'Emission' from there, if you like.

Comment: thanks @RobinBetts but what's the reason for that to be not filled like other parts, now I only have to fill those four rectangles...how can I do that?

Comment: @JassimShaji  The ends of your struts are inside the body of the rocket, so they will show up black; probing rays from those shading-points won't get very far.. and that's how AO works.